# Why does != 0 work but == 1 doesn't work when using bitwise &?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

```
private void displayBinary() {
    int value = 123;
    for (int i = 128; i > 0; i = i / 2) {
        if ((value & i) != 0) System.out.print("1 ");
        else
            System.out.print("0 ");
    }
}
```

The method above successfully writes out 123 in its binary form, where the program outputs
0111101.
However, if I change the !=0 to ==1 in the if statement, it outputs 0000001. Since binary is only 0s and 1s, why doesn't the latter work?

Comment: `value & i` is an integer. All integers different from 0 are not equal to 1. Only one is equal to 1: 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not working with a base-2 number; you're still working with a base-10 `int`.

From this, all numbers for your iteration, except for the last, will fail your `if` condition, since they are not equal to 1.

Comment: Actually, he is working with a base 2 number. But even in base 2, 10, 100, 1000, 10000 or 100000 are not equal to 1.

Comment: Well, the numbers that I did observe flying by in the logs were *representable* in base 2, or could be interepreted as a number in base 2 (128, 64, 32, etc), but the numbers themselves are still base 10.

Comment: All numbers are in base 2. When they're printed, their decimal representation is printed. Bu that's irrelevant anyway. Even if the computer worked natively with base 10 numbers, `i & value` is a number that is not equal to 1 except at the last iteration.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm not disagreeing.  When i get a moment, I'll revise my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you use a bitwise AND, the place of the bit (the digit) matters. 1000 does not equal 1 in either decimal or binary.

Answer (score 0):

(value & i) when it is not 0 wil vay between  1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, and 128 depending on the bit you are testing.